# keep divs with at the end inside another div based on a condition in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` that contains other `div`s. I want to move down the `div`s whose `data-keep-down` attribute is `true` using jQuery. *i.e.* I wanted those to be at the end of other `div`s whose `data-keep-down` attribute is `false`. Below, is my HTML.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="true" data-park-type="meetandgreet" data-amount="65.95" data-type="Recommended"></div>
    <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="false" data-park-type="meetandgreet" data-amount="67.99" data-type="Featured"></div>
    <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="false" data-park-type="meetandgreet" data-amount="78" data-type="Christmas"></div>
    <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="true" data-park-type="meetandgreet" data-amount="54.95" data-type="Special Offer"></div>
    <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="false" data-park-type="park" data-amount="70" data-type="Recommended"></div>
    <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="false" data-park-type="meetandgreet" data-amount="75" data-type="Featured"></div>
    <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="false" data-park-type="meetandgreet" data-amount="84.99" data-type="Christmas"></div>
    <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="false" data-park-type="meetandgreet" data-amount="84.99" data-type=""></div>
    <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="false" data-park-type="meetandgreet" data-amount="94.95" data-type=""></div>
</div>
```

And jQuery used is:

```
$('.parent > div').each(function(index, value) {
    $(this).append(value);
});
```

Please, help. Thanks

Comment: do u mean data-keep-down="true" always and at the top and the rest folow?

Comment: data-keep-down="true" should be always at the END i.e. BELOW others.

Comment: so, you want to reorder the `div`s inside `.parent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".terminalpopular").each(function() {
    if ($(this).data('keep-down')) {
      $(".parent").append($(this));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="true" data-park-type="meetandgreet" data-amount="65.95" data-type="Recommended">65.95</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="false" data-park-type="meetandgreet" data-amount="67.99" data-type="Featured">67.99</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="false" data-park-type="meetandgreet" data-amount="78" data-type="Christmas">78</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="true" data-park-type="meetandgreet" data-amount="54.95" data-type="Special Offer">54.95</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="false" data-park-type="park" data-amount="70" data-type="Recommended">70</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="false" data-park-type="meetandgreet" data-amount="75" data-type="Featured">75</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="false" data-park-type="meetandgreet" data-amount="84.99" data-type="Christmas">84.99</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="false" data-park-type="meetandgreet" data-amount="84.99" data-type="">
    84.99</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="false" data-park-type="meetandgreet" data-amount="94.95" data-type="">94.95</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Attribute Equals Selector [name='value']](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method

```js
$('.parent').append(function() {
  return $(this).find('div[data-keep-down="true"]');
});
//$('.parent > div[data-keep-down="true"]').appendTo('.parent')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="true" data-park-type="meetandgreet" data-amount="65.95" data-type="Recommended">1</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="false" data-park-type="meetandgreet" data-amount="67.99" data-type="Featured">2</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="false" data-park-type="meetandgreet" data-amount="78" data-type="Christmas">3</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="true" data-park-type="meetandgreet" data-amount="54.95" data-type="Special Offer">4</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-keep-down="false" data-park-type="park" data-amount="70" data-type="Recommended">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".terminalpopular").each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('data-keep-down')) {
     $(".parent").append($(this)[0].outerHTML);
  }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8q5wzq7/8/)
//Sorts by True / False as well as Amount

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var $parentElem=$('.parent');
     var keepDownFalse=[];
      var keepDownTrue=[];
   $('.parent > div').each(function(index, value) {
        var $this=$(this);

       if(!$this.data('keep-down')){
            keepDownFalse.push({elem: $this, amount:$this.data('amount')});
       }else{
                keepDownTrue.push({elem: $this, amount:$this.data('amount')});
       }
    });

       keepDownFalse.sort(function(a, b) {
             return a.amount  - b.amount;
       });
       keepDownTrue.sort(function(a, b) {
             return a.amount  - b.amount;
       });
        console.log(keepDownFalse,keepDownTrue);
       $parentElem.empty();
       $.each(keepDownFalse,function(index,value){
           $parentElem.append(value.elem);
       })
        $.each(keepDownTrue,function(index,value){
           $parentElem.append(value.elem);
        });

})
```